Marvel comic where Wolverine thinks Spider-Man is too dangerous
It is when Spider-Man marches towards his target with some superheroes and Wolverine orders all the superheroes to retreat because Spider-Man isn't talking, and Wolverine thinks Spider-Man is too dangerous for any one else to be nearby. It is not the one where he has a throat condition and just doesn't speak.

Which suit was Spidey wearing?
